# Loading spinner with react useEffect hook and Redux and without useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I need to have a loading spinner for my component. I am using react hook `useEffect` and because I am using `redux`, I can't use `useState` in this component.

this is what I've got so far and it doesn't work as expected.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchData } from 'lib';


export default function Example(props) {

  let isFree = false;
  let isLoading = true;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function check() {
      const result = await fetchData(123);

      isLoading = false; // I am aware of react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
      if (!result){
        isFree = true; // I am aware of react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
      }
    }
    check();

    return function cleanup() {
      isLoading = false;
    };

  })

  const bookMe = ()=> {
    if (isLoading) {
      return false;
    }

    // do something
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="column has-text-centered is-loading">
      <div
        className={
          'button is-small is-outlined ' +
          ( isLoading ? ' is-loading' : '')
        }
        onClick={bookMe}
      >
        Select this slot
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note: I tried `useRef` and I didn't get the answer.

Note: I can achieve the solution with class component as bellow. Follow `isLoading`.

But my question is rewrite the whole thing with `useEffect()` and *without* `useState()`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { fetchData } from 'lib';

export default class Example extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;

  state = {
    isFree: false,
    isLoading: true
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;

    fetchData(123).then(result => {
      if (this._isMounted) {
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
      }
      if (!result) {
        if (this._isMounted) {
          this.setState({ isFree: true });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  bookMe = () => {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return false;
    }

    // do something
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="column has-text-centered is-loading">
        <div
          className={
            'button is-small is-outlined ' +
            (this.state.isLoading ? ' is-loading' : '')
          }
          onClick={this.bookMe}
        >select this slot</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: why this statement : "I am using react hook useEffect and because I am using redux, I can't use useState in this component.  ". you are free to use useState. People don't mix controlled and uncontrolled behaviour in a component for better  state managent . That's it Read this link for understanding : https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#common-bugs-when-using-derived-state

Comment: That was a useful blog. thank you. I was trying to keep all the data in Redux and have single source of truth. I agree with what you said.

Comment: Hi MoHo, I posted an answer, does it answer your question?

Comment: I think you are confusing a lot of things. Would like to understand why you cannot use useState, as the first thing. Second, Redux there would be state information but from the "app" point of view, in general components are meant to maintain its own state and use Redux state to store things that potentially other components would access.

Answer (score 3):

> I am using react hook useEffect and because I am using redux, I can't use useState in this component.

**Actually you can use useState.**

- State management is tough and requires decision making. It is not the case that if you use redux you can't use state in your components.
- The question is where you want to manage your request. If you decide to manage your request in the component, it will have to include state.

In general Redux is more appropriate for:

- Storing state that is needed by the various parts of your application.
- Complex state management.

---

> ```
> let isFree = false; 
> let isLoading = true;
> ```

In your code your aren't using useState, but you are actually trying to use state. This can't work because each time the let variable will be newly created by the function.

Comment: @MoHo, if you found my answer helpful you can accept it by clicking on the check icon, and we both get points :-)